# Refactor for loops

Tags: javascript

I have a set of two for loops. The elements are offset by an initial set of elements `numberOfInputs`. I'd like to refactor these into a single loop. each array has the same number of elements. They are both of set by the same `numberOfInputs`.

I've figured out how to do this manually by subtracting the offset when necessary and incrementing by 1 where necessary.

```
    // number of inputs start out as 2.
    var numberOfInputs = 2;
```

```
        // initialize blank html
        html = '';

        //create key inputs
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html += '<div id="s';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='\" class=\"draggyBox-small\">';
          html += elArray[i-numberOfInputs];
          html +='</div>\n';
        }
  
        //create description inputs
        html += '<table id=\"tablestyle\">'
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html += '<td id="row';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='">\n';
          html += '\t\t<div id=\"t';
          html += id;
          html +='" class=\"ltarget\"></div>\n \t</td >\n \t<td  id=\"d2\">'
          html +=dlArray[i-numberOfInputs];
          html +='</td >\n </tr>\n';
        }
        html += '</table>';
```

Comment: Have a second string that you write the contents of the second loop into, then append that to `html` where you had the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Have a loop that creates two chunks of HTML (`html_1` and `html_2`), and append them after the loop finishes:

```
// initialize blank html
html = '';

//create key inputs
var html_1 = ''
var html_2 = '<table id=\"tablestyle\">'
for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
  html_1 += '<div id="s';
  var id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
  html_1 += id;
  html_1 +='\" class=\"draggyBox-small\">';
  html_1 += elArray[i-numberOfInputs];
  html_1 +='</div>\n';

  html_2 += '<td id="row';
  html_2 += id;
  html_2 +='">\n';
  html_2 += '\t\t<div id=\"t';
  html_2 +=i-numberOfInputs;
  html_2 +='" class=\"ltarget\"></div>\n \t</td >\n \t<td  id=\"d2\">'
  html_2 +=dlArray[i-numberOfInputs];
  html_2 +='</td >\n </tr>\n';
}

html = html_1 + html_2 + '</table>'
```

You could also simplify this with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1):

Having two `for` loops that run against the same index is fine. It doesn't change performance significantly and is easier to understand. However, there are other refactoring that could be done to improve both performance and readability.

Note: You're always subtracting `numberOfInputs` so there's no reason to add it to begin with.

```
// assuming `html` and `elArray` had been set earlier
// and that `elArray` is an array of strings

let top = elArray.map((v,i) => 
  `<div id="s${i+1}" class="draggyBox-small">${v}</div>`
).join('\n');

let bottom = elArray.map((v,i) =>
`<tr>
  <td id="row${i+1}">
    <div id="t${i}" class="ltarget"></div>
  </td >
  <td id="d2">${v}</td >
</tr>`
).join('\n');

html = `${top}
<table id="tablestyle">
${bottom}
</table>
`;
```

References:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)